# ERROR: misplaced \omit in a table

Tags: tables

I wrote this code in order to have 6 tables. I cannot understand what to do in order to correct the error of misplaced \omit.

Thanks

```
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.47\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{FRONTAL HIP} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{External Rotation} & \vline\multicolumn{2}{l}{$17^\circ$} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Internal Rotation}  & \vline \multicolumn{2}{l}{$10^\circ$} \\
\hline
\end{tabular} \\
%\captionof{table}{\label{fig:etichetta1}Didascalia 1.}
\vspace{0.5 cm}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.47\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{TRANSVERSE HIP} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{External Rotation} & \vline \multicolumn{2}{l}{$20^\circ$}  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Internal Rotation}  & \vline \multicolumn{2}{l}{$10^\circ$} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\\
%\captionof{table}{\label{fig:etichetta2}Didascalia 2.}
\vspace{0.5 cm}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.47\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{SAGITTAL HIP} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Flexion} & \vline \multicolumn{2}{l}{$115^\circ$}  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Extension}  & \vline \multicolumn{2}{l}{$15^\circ$} \\
\hline
\end{tabular} \\
%\captionof{table}{\label{fig:etichetta1}Didascalia 1.}
\vspace{0.5 cm}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.47\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{SAGITTAL KNEE} \\
\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Flexion} & \vline \multicolumn{2}{l}{$110^\circ$}  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Extension}  & \vline \multicolumn{2}{l}{$0^\circ$} \\
\hline
\end{tabular} \\
%\captionof{table}{\label{fig:etichetta1}Didascalia 1.}
\vspace{0.5 cm}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.47\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{SAGITTAL ANKLE} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Dorsi-Flexion} & \vline \multicolumn{2}{l}{$16^\circ$}  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Plantar-Flexion}  & \vline \multicolumn{2}{l}{$9^\circ$} \\
\hline
\end{tabular} \\
%\captionof{table}{\label{fig:etichetta1}Didascalia 1.}
\vspace{0.5 cm}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.47\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{HENKE ANKLE} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{High Stop} & \vline \multicolumn{2}{l}{$18^\circ$}  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Low Stop}  & \vline \multicolumn{2}{l}{$18^\circ$} \\
\hline
\end{tabular} \\
%\captionof{table}{\label{fig:etichetta1}Didascalia 1.}
\vspace{0.5 cm}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: `\multicolumn` should be the first entry in a cell. You commonly have `\vline \multicolumn`. If your approach is to insert a vertical rule, that should be included inside the `\multicolumn` macro's 3rd argument. See if that makes a difference to your compilation.

Comment: @Werner the vertical rule should be in the second argument of `\multicolumn`: `\multicolumn{2}{|l}{...}`.

Comment: @Skillmon: ...right.

Answer (score 4):

`\multicolumn` has to be the first element in a `tabular` cell. In your case you're using

```
\vline \multicolumn{2}{l}{...}
```

If the intent is to produce a vertical rule to the left of the column, rather use

```
\multicolumn{2}{|l}{...}
```